# How can I make Stream Writer overwrite a txt file in unity (c#)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, streamwriter

I'm trying to keep track of some information by using a text file. I want the text file to reset every time I write in it so that I don't get a bunch of old information. Is there any way for me to do this?

```cs
void WriteString(string text, string path) {
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true);
    writer.Write(text);
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code; just include the code directly.

Comment: I guess no one bothers to google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Your Text File Path
string path = @"";

// The Text You Want To Write inside The File
string content = "";

// This Method Clears Whatever Text It Finds in the File and Writes the new Content (overwrites the text file)
File.WriteAllText(path, content);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change "true" to "false" in the constructor call, it will overwrite the file.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, false);
```